# How to list all modern UI apps?

Tags: c++, windows-8, modern-ui, modern-runtime

I would like to list all Modern UI apps installed on my Windows 8 machine.

Is there a way to list all installed Modern UI apps from a standard desktop application (with administrator permissions).

Comment: All Modern UI apps seem to be registered in the registry under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes", that start with "App*". Where "/Application/ApplicationName" is the name of the application and "/Application/AppUserModelID" is the unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Powershell and the [Get-AppxPackage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

Nigel has the correct answer ;)

This is a complement to launch automatically with administrator permissions :
(I'm using this trick a few month ago, so i don't have any longer the source. I will edit this post if I'll found it.)

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
  # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
  $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
  $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
  clear-host
}
else
{
  # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

  # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
  $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

  # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
  $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

  # Indicate that the process should be elevated
  $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

  # Start the new process
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

  # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
  exit
}

# List all apps
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```